# Get Outlook folder size

Tags: c++, outlook

Is there a way to programatically get the size of a specific Outlook folder. (I know I can navigate the folder and get the size of each mail item but I'm looking for a way to directly get the total size)
For MailItem objects there is a size attribute but I don't know if for MAPIFolder objects there is one too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some store providers expose the PR_MESSAGE_SIZE property on folders, but most likely it will be missing or 0.

Your best bet is to just sum up the size of all the message in the folder. Do not loop through all messages, you can use the Table object (returned by MAPIFolder.GetTable) to retrieve the PR_MESSAGE_SIZE property for all items without actually opening them.